# How to reshape a shape to fit text in MS VISIO?

Tags: vba, visio

I have a shape on MS Visio and I'd like to reshape it depending on the text inside it.

I tried the following line of code :

```
element.Cells("Width").Formula = "=GUARD(TEXTWIDTH(TheText))"
```

But that's not working, there are still some spaces in the shape, I'd like to fit the text without any spaces left.

Do you have an idea how to do that ?

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is probably better suited for SU, but here is the solution:
That's the paragraph spacing you are seeing.

In Code: use the [TopMargin Cell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/topmargin-cell-text-block-format-section) or whichever one you need.

Or manually set them to 0 and it should work:

[image: Paragraph Option]

[image: Paragraph Window]

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked with those 2 lines :

```
element.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowText, visTxtBlkLeftMargin) = 0
element.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowText, visTxtBlkRightMargin) = 0
```